# Unix alias command not working as expected

Tags: unix, shell, command-line, alias, ksh

i have a command to kill some processes as below:

```
kill -9 `psu|grep MF1pp|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'`
```

the command works perfectly fine

```
>psu|grep MF1pp|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'
29390
29026
$>kill -9 `psu|grep MF1pp|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'`
$>psu|grep MF1pp|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'
```

when i create an alias as below and run it:

```
alias killaf="kill -9 `psu|grep MF1pp|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'`"



$> psu|grep MF1pp|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'
5487
5272
$>killaf
ksh: kill: bad argument count
```

gives the above error.

can anyone tell me what could be the issue?

Comment: @benjamin they're voting that it be moved to superuser - personally I disagree as it's clearly a shell script issue.

Comment: Probably because it's not programming related - it's better suited to serverfault.com (system admin.)

Comment: It's clearly a programming problem with shell quoting semantics. That's not a system management issue; anybody writing a shell script (or alias, as in this case) for any purpose might have the exact same problem.

Comment: Please don't use `kill -9`: http://sial.org/howto/shell/kill-9/ and http://speculation.org/garrick/kill-9.html and http://aplawrence.com/SCOFAQ/FAQ_scotec6killminus9.html

Comment: Also, don't use backticks.  $() is a much clearer syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command line whereby you're setting up the alias is not quoted correctly. Specifically, the back-quote embedded subcommand is being executed at the time you set up the alias, and not later when you actually want to run the alias.

Try setting it up this way:

```
alias killaf='kill -9 `psu|grep MF1pp|grep -v grep|awk '\''{print $2}'\''`'
```

**edit:** I fixed the quotes around the `awk` command - it's tricky to embed single-quotes when you're already single-quoting.

Comment: why exactly are the `'\'` 's required?

Answer (score 1):

This is what xargs is for:

```
alias killaf='ps -fu $USER | awk '/[M]F1pp/ {print $2}' | xargs kill -9'
```

(untested)

BTW: I don't know why `bash` supports aliases.  I prefer to use functions:

```
killaf() { ps -fu $USER | awk '/[M]F1pp/ {print $2}' | xargs kill -9; }
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to use an alias? use a sub routine instead. And i assume you mean `ps` command as i don't know what `psu` is

```
killmyprocess(){
  ps -eo pid,comm |awk '$2~/MF1pp/{
    cmd="kill -9 "$1
    print cmd
  #  system(cmd) #uncomment to use
  }'
}
```

Comment: psu here is `ps-fu $USER`.its again an alias.

Answer (score -1):

Try escaping the $ in awk, usually it must be escaped to make it work fine:

```
alias killaf="kill -9 `psu|grep MF1pp|grep -v grep|awk '{print \$2}'`"
```